# Paying tax while working abroad remotely

Tags: taxes, remote

Please redirect me if there's a more appropriate site to post this question on.

Taking this hypothetical scenario:

- I'm a citizen of the UK
- I live abroad (not in the EU or the US)
- I freelance remotely in the US
- My salary goes into a UK bank account

Which country do I need to pay tax?

I've checked gov.uk which is usually very clear but I can't find this particular scenario.

Comment: This needs to be answered by a tax professional in the country where you live. Allow me one wording change. If you are freelancing, then you don't have a salary. You are receiving payments for service which is not salary, but business transaction.